# unhiding asp button onclick of the html button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 2 buttons on my page. First one is a html button and the next is an asp button. Now i want to hide the asp button on page load and want to unhide the same on the onclick of the html button. Can anyone help me with this ??

Answer (score 0):

**.aspx html/javascript code**

```
<head>
function UnhideButtons(buttonName){
if(buttonName == 'aspButton'){
document.getElementbyId(htmlButton).visiblity = "visible";
}
}
</head>

<body>
<asp:Button id="aspButton" style="visibility:hidden" Text="ASP Button"/>
<Button id="htmlButton" text="HTML Button" onClick=UnhideButtons("aspButton")
</body>
```